# Why does rpm -i <package> fail on a dependency that I have installed?

Tags: software-installation, yum, rpm

I tried installing the following package:

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -i libmicrohttpd-0.9.22-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

But I got an error for failed dependencies:

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -i libmicrohttpd-0.9.22-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
libgnutls.so.28()(64bit) is needed by libmicrohttpd-0.9.22-1.el7.centos.x86_64
libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit) is needed by libmicrohttpd-0.9.22-1.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Naturally I tried installing these dependencies:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install libgnutls.so.28
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.vooservers.com
 * epel: pkg.adfinis-sygroup.ch
 * extras: mirrors.melbourne.co.uk
 * updates: mirrors.melbourne.co.uk
Package gnutls-3.3.26-9.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

But as you can see above I am told that the package is "already installed" and there is "nothing to do".

This makes no sense to me if the package is already installed then why is the installation of libmicrohttpd-0.9.22-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm failing  because it can not find this dependency?

Answer (score 2):

You have installed `gnutls-3.3.26-9.el7.i686`, but that is not `libgnutls.so.28()(64bit)`, it is 32bits.

You need to install `gnutls-3.3.26-9.el7.x64_86`, which is the correct architecture to match what you're trying to install.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You were installing `i686` which is a `32-bit` library.The error clearly states that `libmicrohttpd` needs a `64-bit` library.

Refer this [link](https://pkgs.org/download/libgnutls.so.28()(64bit)) to get the required RPM.

You can also configure `yum` via `/etc/yum.conf` to install the best suited package for the underlying architecture. The parameter to be modified in `yum.conf` is `multilib_policy`.

```
multilib_policy Can be set to 'all' or 'best'. 
multilib_policy=all
```

All means install all possible arches for any package you want to install. Therefore yum install foo will install `foo.i386 and foo.x86_64 on x86_64`, if it is available. Best means install the best arch for this platform, only. For more refer this [page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/yum.conf) and this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/654677/yum-always-install-both-32-and-64-bit-when-available).

To know the underlying archietcture , run
`uname -m`

Comment: I'm not savvy when it comes to arch types, did not know that i686 was 32-bit. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkMark added a command to know the underlying architecture of your system.

Answer (score 0):

it is always a better idea to use `yum` directly in order to let `yum` manage the dependencies for you:

```
yum install libmicrohttpd-0.9.22-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Relative path need not be specified for `yum` like `./`

Comment: all-right, I changed that. But it does no harm.

Comment: No, It harms actually, the `yum` actually searches for the package named `./libmicrohttpd-0.9.22-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm` instead of `libmicrohttpd-0.9.22-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm` if `./` is specified and eventually fails saying `No package ./libmicrohttpd-0.9.22-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm available`.

Comment: @saisasanka: the user is trying to install a package file, otherwise `rpm -i` wouldn't even bother. That is why in this case using the relative path would not change anything. You are right that it would fail if you would like yum to search for the package in its repositories.

Comment: ok. My thought was, since you mentioned `yum`, the OP need not even get the specific RPM manually to install via `yum` and so I suggested the edit. :)